# Safari on iOS 11.1.2 is using the wrong email address

Tags: ios

If I go to a site where I am purchasing something and I click on Autofill, I’m presented with a pop up that has the following options:

- Custom
- Home
- Work
- Customize
- Other Contact
- Cancel

If I select home, it uses my work email.  If I use work, it uses no email.  If I click Customize and then click email, it shows several email addresses and the word “home” is next to my work email address.  I can click any of the listed email addresses to “check” it as the default.

How do I fix it so that my “home” email address is my personal email.  How do I fix it so that work uses my work email?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Contacts > find your name and click on it > click Edit > and you will see that you can choose which email you want to be your personal, work etc.

Comment: I’ve done that before I submitted this question and it still has the behavior mentioned above.

Comment: strange. did you try erasing all the emails under your name, and then saving them again?

Comment: Yes, but now the home and work ones are missing.  Apple smh

Comment: Do you remember them? Just add them again to your contact info